# Add name of file that is playing?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I was wondering is it possible to add the name of the file the plugin is playing?

I have added an mp3 to my page here just to test the plugin. http://pdfelectronics.com/about/

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Define dynamically your mediaelement object (see here: [Mediaelements.js: override features attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939414/mediaelements-js-override-features-attributes)) and add this in its success callback:

```
$('.mejs-mediaelement').css('color', '#FFFF00').html('NAME of your audio');
```